Can stockfish provide analysis with non-standard pieces like knooks?
I wanted to know if stockfish can provide evaluation if there are non-standard pieces like knook?

There is a fork of Stockfish that can. It's called Fairy-Stockfish. It can play many variants, and my understanding is that mostly it does so quite well.
